# Why is post used in a search route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey fellow stackerenos!

Consider this snippet of code I found in a tutorial on custom routes:

In routes.rb,

```
resources :users do
  resources :tweets
  post :search, on: :collection
end
```

Why is the action "post" and not "get"?  As I understand it, "post" is used to insert into a table.  But this creates a custom route to search all the tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Form submissions are generally sent as POST requests (whether or not this results in inserting into a table is immaterial). Presumably this route is invoked by a user submitting a "search" form.